# how to make visible cadre around buttons

Tags: c#

how can i visible cadre around my buttons  in c# forms. that whenever I click on it or it runs the cadr will be visible around it? 
please get me the code example

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Does cadre means border? Do you want to draw border around button?

Comment: I do'nt know what the border  exactly is .but i mean than when I run the proramm or select the buttun then around the button that is selected  a line will be visible

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the dotted line, that shows where the focus is, there is nothing you need to do; tab to the button (during runtime!) and it will show.

If you mean the change in appearence during the click, this also happens by itself.

If you want any other changes during the click, set and reset them during the MouseDown and MouseUp events, not the Click, as this will be too late.

If you are looking for still something else, please specify more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change the border appearance of button. Use the `Button.FlatAppearance` to change the border styles. But this will work only when the style is `Flat`.

Sample code:

```
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red;
```